# Interval doesn't stop on mouseout

Tags: jquery, intervals, mouseleave, mouseout

The interval "myInterval" won't stop if I move the mouse out of the element which triggers the interval function before. Why doesn't it stop?

```
$(".postimagepic").mouseenter(function () {
    var link = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'asdf.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'user': 'yy',
                'topost': link
            },
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

Comment: `myInterval` is _private_ to the `mouseenter` callback function. Declare the variable above the event binding code. **Code:** `var myInterval; .... $(".postimagepic").mouseenter(function() { myInterval = setInterval....`. Also, use `hover`.

Comment: Moritz, two of the key tools in web development are your browser's web console (which is showing you an error, if you look) and its built-in debugger. Use F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or Cmd+Shift+I to open your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `myInterval` is *private* to the `mouseenter` callback function and hence not accessible outside of that function. To make it accessible from `mouseout` callback function, declare the variable outside of the function.

```
var myInterval; // Define it here to make it global

$(".postimagepic").mouseenter(function () {
    var link = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    // Accessible here
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

---

I'll also suggest to use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events.

```
var myInterval; // Define it here to make it global

$(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
    var link = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

Comment: Tried to but my reputation is still under 15... :/ I´ll do it when I reach 15 points! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make globle variable, declare the variable name without **`var`** keyword.

As below

```
$(".postimagepic").mouseenter(function () {
        var link = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
        myInterval = setInterval(function () { //change here only
            $.ajax({
                url: 'asdf.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'user': 'yy',
                    'topost': link
                },
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });
```